# Cannot automate a remote program using python and dogtail, no graphical interface in the remote server…

Tags: python, linux, ssh, automation

I wrote a code using python and dogtail (automation program from redhat) to automate a program. This program is running in a virtual machine without desktop graphical environment.

I ssh the virtual machine and run the program and the graphical interface start on my machine.
I then run my python program on my machine to automate this program. And here is the problem... the python code does not work because it did not recognize the remote program that is run via ssh. And if I move the python code to the virtual machine it asks me to enable the “assistive technologies” and I can’t because I do not have gnome or any graphical environment in the virtual machine?
All used operating systems are Ubuntu…
I try to find solution everywhere without success. I wish I explain the problem clearly, if not please let me know... 
Please help… thank you

Comment: Dogtail is a GUI testing program - I don't think it's going to work without a graphical environment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dogtail-run-headless-next binary in dogtail and it should be able to start X (or more precisely gdm service) and log in (with autologin of test user). Then it's parameter is executed in desktop environment.

we use (under root)
sudo -u test dogtail-run-headless-next "./your_script"

I hope this will enable assistive technology, too. If not you can always use:
if not isA11yEnabled():
    enableA11y(True)

You can automate ssh into a machine via pexpect. See new: http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pxssh.html

or older:
http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html

Answer (score 0):

A modern solution is to run the script via the X virtual framebuffer command like so

```
apt install xvfb
....
xvfb-run /path/to/script.py
```

It appears that modern Linux security policies no longer allow `dogtail-run-headless-next` to run as the script relies on reading all of `/proc`, which is clearly a security hazard.